# Killing Bermuda Grass

Tags: grass

There's Bermuda grass gradually spreading from my neighbor's yard. I'd like it gone and replaced with some other type of grass. What are my options? I've tried a poison specifically designed for Bermuda, but it's not that effective. I've used a sheet of plastic, and that works, but not great. A childhood neighbor would burn off his zoysia, but I'm not sure that's allowed where I'm at, or if it would work. Is there a grass I could overplant that would dominate it? Is there a non-poison option that would work? Time is not a huge issue. That is, it doesn't have to be finished this year.

[image: The grass]

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: @blackthumb - there's a pic.

Comment: You have a huge yard, you can really do high density chicken grazing with a chicken tractor to get them to kill the grass. Look into the jersey giants as they are like small lawn mowers, and since your city probably has just a limit on the number of chickens when you're done with them you will get about 60 LBS of chicken meat out of them (10 lbs chickens) as well as eggs while you employ them.

Comment: Maybe there's a better way to explain that our city allows no chickens. Zero. None. Nada. Chickens are not an option. Period. And if they were, the reading I've done suggests that many people raise chickens and their lawns do fine. So, it may or may not work.

Comment: do rabbits then, and have them eat all of the grass, and cut it really short. check the city ordinances.

Answer (score 2):

Get chickens, and let them graze the grass off completely, then reseed it with something else you have more of a desire to grow working section by section of the yard.

Comment: Cool idea! My city doesn't allow chickens. :(

Comment: what about paving over it, or using a big tarp?

Comment: I'd like grass there, so no pavement. A tarp is a possibility. I used plastic over a section of it, but the the yard is then pretty unsightly for several months.

Comment: Why can't you even have 1 chicken in your yard with a controlled fence area?